# Cannot extract error message from error.message

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, axios

I have this line of code in my express app:

```
 catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err.message);
      }
```

when i console log the error I get this message:

```
name: 'TokenExpiredError',
message: 'jwt expired',
```

but when I recieve the error in my client using axios request like so:

```
catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message)
```

I get this : `Request failed with status code 500`

how can I access the original massage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to simply catch the error, a 500 error is just a 500 error (with it's own generic message).

You need to extract the message you send in the response from the response body. This is from the github issues pages for axios https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960:

```
axios
.post('ajax/register/otp', this.registerData)
.then(function (response) {
       ...
})
.catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
 });
```